# firebase reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential facebook user credential

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to write a function to reauthenticate a firebase user that is logged in with a facebook account. For the email I create the credentials from the email and password but with Facebook no password is stored for that user. I tried to find this in the docs but couldn't find

```
 let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 let credential = '';

    //User created with Email
    if(user.providerData[0].providerId === "password") {
      credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        user.email,
        this.state.password
      );
    }

   //User created with Facebook
   if(user.providerData[0].providerId === "facebook.com") {
      credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
         ? // <= User Email, Token 
       )
   } 
   user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function(){
         user.delete().then(function() {             
         }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
          }
      }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error)
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the FacebookAuthProvider.credential() signature, you will need the OAuth token / accessToken to create the credential.

You can extract the accessToken when the user logs in:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
})
```

The example was extracted from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login where you can find more info about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reauthenticate a Facebook user, simply use `reauthenticateWithPopup` or `reauthenticateWithRedirect`, assume you used `signInWithPopup` or `signInWithRedirect` to sign in the user with Facebook.

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithPopup(provider)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // User successfully reauthenticated.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error.
  });
```